# Apache maven : Is Yum now supported?

Tags: apache, maven, yum

I found that for some time, standard yum commands "yum install maven" 
did not work on various linux versions.

But now on Fedora 18, I'm finding that maven is very easily "yum installable".

Has maven moved to explicitly supporting yum repos ?

Or is the idiomatic way to install it still a simple download ?

Comment: On Fedora 18, `yum install mvn` works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven itself does not support yum repositories. If you are simple searching for installation just use the [download page](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi). For artifacts which can be produced by Maven you can use a repository manager (Nexus or Artifactory but in commericial versions) which supports yum repositories.